# How to read email from one with gmail API?

Tags: .net, google-api

I follow this Google API .NET guide :

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet

But I don't know about userId

```
// Define parameters of request.
UsersResource.LabelsResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.Labels.List("me");
```

I want to find for someone (eg: someone@gmail.com). But when I change "me", I got an Exception.

Can you help me, I want to read an email from someone in my gmail.

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Invalid user id specified in
>   request/Delegation denied [403] Errors [ Message[Invalid user id
>   specified in request/Delegation denied] Location[ - ]
>   Reason[forbidden] Domain[global] ]

Comment: Since you have an Exception, please copy the complete error message into your question. Also, what did you try exactly for this Exception.

Comment: So sorry this is Exception's message "'Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Invalid user id specified in request/Delegation denied [403]
Errors [
 Message[Invalid user id specified in request/Delegation denied] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]
]"

Answer (score 1):

You simply cannot read other's email without their consent.

If you have consent, ask them to follow "Step 1: Turn on the Gmail API" and send you the client_secret.json file, copy it to your output folder and rerun the program. You should see their emails now.

Step 1 ensures "they" have enabled API access.

Comment: I follow that sample and it work. But it work with userId is "me" only. Have you got any sample get email with google api ? Show for me thank a lot!